# Major number 259 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, devices

If I execute `lsblk -p` command, the following is the output :

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
/dev/loop0         7:0    0  99,4M  1 loop /snap/core/11606
/dev/loop1         7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2         7:2    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop3         7:3    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop4         7:4    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop5         7:5    0  99,3M  1 loop /snap/core/11743
/dev/loop6         7:6    0  55,4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop7         7:7    0 131,6M  1 loop /snap/docker/796
/dev/loop8         7:8    0 242,4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
/dev/loop9         7:9    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop10        7:10   0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13170
/dev/loop11        7:11   0   165M  1 loop /snap/postman/144
/dev/loop12        7:12   0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
/dev/loop13        7:13   0  65,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop14        7:14   0  88,1M  1 loop /snap/remmina/5028
/dev/loop15        7:15   0 102,3M  1 loop /snap/remmina/5070
/dev/loop16        7:16   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop17        7:17   0  65,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop18        7:18   0  10,9M  1 loop /snap/ncspot/141
/dev/loop19        7:19   0 168,1M  1 loop /snap/postman/147
/dev/loop20        7:20   0  61,8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop21        7:21   0   4,5M  1 loop /snap/spt/275
/dev/nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─/dev/nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─/dev/nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 312,1G  0 part 
├─/dev/nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   900M  0 part 
├─/dev/nvme0n1p5 259:5    0    17G  0 part 
├─/dev/nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   9,6G  0 part /home
├─/dev/nvme0n1p7 259:7    0   3,8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─/dev/nvme0n1p8 259:8    0 111,8G  0 part /
```

This [article](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-the-lsblk-command) mentions that the number in `MAJ:MIN` column are the numbers used by the kernel to internally identify the devices, the first number specifying the device type (8 for example, is used for SCSI disks). Also, [one of the answers on this question unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73988/linux-major-and-minor-device-numbers) mentions this [reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) that shows two columns, the left one (i.e 1 block, 2 char, 2 block, etc and the right column that shows the description (i.e memory devices, RAM disk, etc.

From my `lsblk -p` output above, I have major number 7 and 259. What does that mean? The only number 259 and 7 that I found from this [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) only this text :

```
259 block   Block Extended Major
            Used dynamically to hold additional partition minor
            numbers and allow large numbers of partitions per device



7 char  Virtual console capture devices
          0 = /dev/vcs      Current vc text (glyph) contents
          1 = /dev/vcs1     tty1 text (glyph) contents
            ...
         63 = /dev/vcs63    tty63 text (glyph) contents
         64 = /dev/vcsu     Current vc text (unicode) contents
        65 = /dev/vcsu1     tty1 text (unicode) contents
            ...
        127 = /dev/vcsu63   tty63 text (unicode) contents
        128 = /dev/vcsa     Current vc text/attribute (glyph) contents
        129 = /dev/vcsa1    tty1 text/attribute (glyph) contents
            ...
        191 = /dev/vcsa63   tty63 text/attribute (glyph) contents

        NOTE: These devices permit both read and write access.
```

Comment: Your last part is not the answer to your question? 7 is a virtual device (loop devices are virtual). 259 is an actual disk and partition the numbers 1-8 are partitions (where boundary fillers are also counted).

Comment: @Rinzwind because this article https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-the-lsblk-command mentions that 'The second column is named MAJ:MIN: those are the numbers used by the kernel to internally identify the devices, the first number specifying the device type' so, from my `lsblk -p` ouput, can I conclude that the number 259 means the device type is 'Block Extended Major' ?

Comment: Yes it does.  NVMe device is an SSD using a PCIE connection (older version used SSD with SATA),